# Japanese bunker and evil voodoo magic. Trapped inhabitants must kill themselves to escape(?)

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

A group of people go to an island. There's a woman who wants to buy a piece of land there to build a resort but she discovers some underground bunker so they go to check it out but there is some evil stuff in there

They stumble upon some voodoo dolls and in there they see their fears and only way to get out is to kill yourself and they all realize that but one, he remains to the end and if you're the last then you will be stuck there for life.

He stays and after that another groups comes back in there and he goes to one of them to see that it’s himself and he tells him to kill himself but he doesn’t listen....just like first time

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to better understand how our site works. You've orovided a reasonable plot summary, but there may be additional information you could add to your post to make it easier to find your movie. Look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867) for ideas on additional information to [edit] into your post. For example: Roughly when did you see this movie? Did you see it at a theatre, on broadcast TV, via a recording, or streaming? What language was the movie in? Was it black and white, or color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [Gehenna: Where Death Lives](https://www.metacritic.com/movie/gehenna-where-death-lives) (2016).

> Paulina and Tyler visit Saipan to locate the ideal property for their
>   new company resort. After finding the perfect location, they discover
>   a hidden cave on the property and decide to explore with Alan, their
>   local coordinator, and his assistant, Pepe. The cave reveals a long
>   abandoned Japanese military base, dating back to WW2. Further
>   investigation uncovers several dried up corpses, but curiosity
>   outweighs fear and they walk further. From the darkness, an elderly
>   man approaches; a man barely recognizable as human. Horrible
>   deformities ravage his frail body, as if he had been living in the
>   cave for his entire life. Alan panics and pushes the old man backward,
>   sending him crashing into the wall with a force that ends the old
>   man’s life. A deafening explosion sends rocks and rubble everywhere.
>   The intensity of the turbulence shakes the entire cave, knocking the
>   group unconscious and seals them in the cave. They wake to find the
>   dead body of the old man has disappeared, as well as the other
>   corpses. Desperate to find an exit, they wander further into cave and
>   encounter more sinister secrets in it depths. As the various sources
>   and clues unwind the cave’s mysteries, they’ll learn that the most
>   shocking conclusion still awaits them

Warning. Trailer is deeply NSFW

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seHmt6YwVH0)

Comment: Yes! Thank you 

Comment: Seems to be 2016 rather than 2018, though.